# SHAP Exception: Additivity check failed in TreeExplainer

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

I am trying to create shap values for a single row for the local explanation but I am consistently getting this error. I tried various methods but still couldn't able to fix them.

Things I did so far -

created the randomized decision tree model -

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
extra_tree = ExtraTreesRegressor(random_state=42)
extra_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Then try to calculate the shap values -

```
# create a explainer object
explainer = shap.Explainer(extra_tree)    
explainer.expected_value
array([15981.25812347])

#calculate shap value for a single row
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(pd.DataFrame(X_train.iloc[9274]).T)
```

This gives me this error -

```
Exception: Additivity check failed in TreeExplainer! Please ensure the data matrix you passed to the explainer is the same shape that the model was trained on. If your data shape is correct then please report this on GitHub. Consider retrying with the feature_perturbation='interventional' option. This check failed because for one of the samples the sum of the SHAP values was 25687017588058.968750, while the model output was 106205.580000. If this difference is acceptable you can set check_additivity=False to disable this check.
```

The shape of training and the single row, I passed has the same number of columns

```
X_train.shape
(421570, 164)
(pd.DataFrame(X_train.iloc[9274]).T).shape
(1, 164)
```

And I don't think, it should cause any problem. But to make sure, I also tried to bring the right shape using reshape method.

```
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train.iloc[9274].values.reshape(1, -1))

X_train.iloc[9274].values.reshape(1, -1).shape
(1, 164)
```

Which also doesn't solve the problem. So, I thought maybe I also need to match the number of rows. So I created a small data frame and try to test it.

```
train = pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis="columns")
train_small = train.sample(n=500, random_state=42)
X_train_small = train_small.drop("Weekly_Sales", axis=1).copy()
y_train_small = train_small["Weekly_Sales"].copy()

# train a randomized decision tree model
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
extra_tree_small = ExtraTreesRegressor(random_state=42)
extra_tree_small.fit(X_train_small, y_train_small)

# create a explainer object
explainer = shap.Explainer(extra_tree_small)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train_small)

# I also tried to add the y value like this 
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train_small, y_train_small)
```

**But nothing is working.**

One of the people on GitHub suggested uninstalling and [reinstall](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/941)
shap's latest version from GitHub:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/slundberg/shap.git
```

Also tried it still not working.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you transposing the row? Why not just pass `shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train.iloc[9274])`

Comment: Please [reprex]

Answer (score 3):

I'm still not sure why you are transposing or trying to change the shape of your input, as that is not in [the examples](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/tree/master/notebooks), but I think the solution below should exemplify using [`sklearn's ExtraTreeRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeRegressor.html) and using SHAP. Please note, I did not have access to your data so I had to [generate my own data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_regression.html).

*Note -- I set this to 1000 samples initially so it would run fast. I later set it to 10000 and it ran, just a little slower.*

Let me know if you have questions:

```
# Import statements
import shap, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, pandas as pd, numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

## Generating data since none was provided
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=50, n_informative=45, noise=1, random_state=8)
# Convert data to pandas dataframe as in question
X = pd.DataFrame(data=X, columns=["Feature_{}".format(i) for i in range(X.shape[1])])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=8, test_size=0.2)

## Creating model per question
extra_tree = ExtraTreesRegressor(random_state=42, verbose=2)
extra_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

"""
Provided code:
explainer = shap.Explainer(extra_tree) 
"""
# Our Code
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(extra_tree) 

# Visualize one value
single_shap_value = explainer(X_test.sample(n=1))
shap.summary_plot(single_shap_value, feature_names=X_test.columns, plot_type='bar')
plt.show()

# Visualize all values
shap_values = explainer(X_test)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, feature_names=X_test.columns)
plt.show()
```

This produces images like below:
[image]

[image]

I believe your issues are related to my comment which is about your data shape. If you keep things intact, you should be just fine.

Some notes:

```
python -V
3.8.8
print(sklearn.__version__)
print(shap.__version__)
0.24.1
0.39.0
```

Comment: the code you wrote works perfectly fine. But when I try to replicate on my own data I am still getting the error.  Don't know why is this happening? After doing some more checks I will let you know.

Comment: And about the reshaping of the data - if you check the dimension of the X_train.sample(n=1).ndim you will see that it's 2. I was using iloc accessor which returns a series so its ndim will be 1 but the model was trained with 2d data. That's why I am reshaping the data. If you run single_shap_value = explainer(X_train.iloc[0]), you will also get this error. The way I was reshaping was not very pythonic, I should have passed the number in a list like this  X_train.iloc[[0]], the ndim of this will be 2 and a pandas data frame instead of a series, which I saw in the document a few minutes ago.

Comment: @bholaprasad if you simply plug your data in to `train_test_split` and keep my code exactly, does it work? Additionally, you are correct, a single sample (as per the documentation in my answer) should be passed like `dataframe.iloc[[index]]` with double `[` and `]`.

Comment: If you post your data, perhaps I can help @bholaprasad

Comment: I tried it again as you described but it is still not working. The only changes I have made is the preprocessing of data for filling missing values and one hot encoding. The data was taken from this kaggle competition - https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-store-sales-forecasting and to see what kind of transformation I have done, please look at this github notebook - https://github.com/bprasad26/walmart-recruiting-store-sales-forecasting/blob/main/notebooks/09_ml_models_part6.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

2 years later but for future readers. I am facing the same problem when using a `Pandas DataFrame` instead of a `Numpy Array`. Assuming `x_train` is a `DataFrame`, so simply changing from:

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model, data=x_train.sample(1000))
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x_train)
```

to:

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model, data=x_train.sample(1000))
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(np.array(x_train))
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience this is caused by a few minor predictors missing in the current data set passed to `shap_values` function, as compared to the training set on which the SHAP-supporting model was trained (i.e. the model the passed to `shap.TreeExplainer`) was trained on.

This happens routinely with OHE encoder, when you remove a cat variable or two after encoding to binary columns and now the cat var is missing from the dataset.

A **quick workaround** (which does not affect much the features ranking by SHAP values in the above scenario where OHE is used very sparingly) is to **switch off the additivity check**, like this:

```
check_additivity = False
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X=data_x, y=data_y, check_additivity=check_additivity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a direct call to the explainer

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
shap_values = explainer(X)
```

here X is your row.

Comment: passing this way causing error - 
Exception: Additivity check failed in TreeExplainer! Please ensure the data matrix you passed to the explainer is the same shape that the model was trained on. If your data shape is correct then please report this on GitHub. Consider retrying with the feature_perturbation='interventional' option. This check failed because for one of the samples the sum of the SHAP values was 25687017588058.968750, while the model output was 106205.580000. If this difference is acceptable you can set check_additivity=False to disable this check.

Comment: this might sound stupid but is it so that you need to pass the whole matrix instead of a single row.